# Where are the Kindergartners hiding?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I've been roped into a game of Hide and Seek with a bunch of four year olds, and I've managed to find five of them, but can't find the sixth. Where are they all hiding?

Should I be able to find all six before recruiting Tweek, Craig, and Token? (I know that I can find five of them...)

Answer (score 10):

The six Kindergartners are in the following locations:

- Outside Mr. Slave's house
- In the sewers
- Inside the bank (behind the desk at the top-left)
- Outside the tower of peace (behind a lamp post)
- Starks Pond
- The farm (Bottom left corner)

They are a side-quest, and are not required for continuing on with the main quest. Although they do boost your friend list by 6 once you do find them all and return to the park.